# Sorting questions, for which no votes have been cast, by "newest" doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When I type `votes:0` in the search box I am shown a list of questions, for which no votes have been cast, sorted by relevance.  When I click the "newest" tab to see them sorted by date, I am shown the search options help page instead of the list of questions I wanted.

For some reason it is rewriting my search to look for `newest:0` instead of `votes:0`.  I look at the URL and I see this

`http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=newest%3a0`

What I want is this (which I can manually enter and get the desired result).

`http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=votes%3a0`

Comment: Same with the other tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great find - a fix will be pushed in tonight's deployment.